# css dropdown menu : submenu won't align left

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu with css that I found on [csswizardry](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/)

For some reason, the submenus don't automatically align to the left and I can't seem to find the problem. 
I think it has to do with

```
#nav li:hover ul{ 
left:0;
}
```

or

```
#nav ul{
background:#fff; 
background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
```

but can't seem to find what it is. :(

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/gD5rJ/

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gD5rJ/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UL`s has default 40px left margin (or padding in any browsers).

```
#nav li ul {margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0;}
```

Comment: Hi panther, thank you for replying. This works.

I was however under the impression that list-style: none in this:

    #nav ul{
    background:#fff; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 

was supposed to remove all defaults? Did I misunderstand?

Comment: No, `list-style: none` removes the disc from `LI`, not all default styles. Next, `list-style` is for `LI`, but margin (or padding) is on `UL`. And `position: absolute; left: 0; margin-left: 40px` means that the element will be 40px from left parent edge (left: 0 + margin-left: 40px).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I have romove the margin value and left padding value
    #nav li ul {margin: 0; padding-left: 0;}

Comment: Thank you for replying. Same question for you as panther if you have any idea. TIA! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

add `padding:0px` to `#nav li:hover ul`

see it on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/gD5rJ/1/)

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#nav ul{
    background:#fff; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 
}
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px; 
    float:none;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; 
}
#nav li:hover ul{ 
    left:0;
    padding:0px;
}
#nav li:hover a{ 
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#nav li:hover ul a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ 
    background:#333;
}
```